# SignInManager not recognized in asp.net core 2

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

Using asp.net core 2.0 (sdk 2.1.2) and when using `SignInManager<TUser>`, my VS Studio 2017 doesn't recognize it.  I have *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity* imported.  It does recognize `UserManager` and `RoleManager`, but not `SignInManager`.  Not sure what is wrong.  Below is my csproj file:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore\2.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.identity.core\2.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.identity.stores\2.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>    
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.options\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

This worked before in my .net core 1.1 app (although I'm not converting, I'm starting from scratch another project).

Comment: I don't see `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` in the above. `RoleManager` and `UserManager` are both in the assembly `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core` whereas `SignInManager` is in the assembly `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use nuget, all you should need is the following:

```xml
 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the project is not a web application, go to "Manage Nuget Package" and install 
**`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`**